# CMake on Raspberry Pi: Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, trinitycore

I'm trying to compile [TrinityCore](http://collab.kpsn.org/display/tc/How-to_Linux) on Raspberry Pi. However, it cannot find Threads.

```
-- Detected 32-bit platform
-- UNIX: Using jemalloc
-- UNIX: Using default configuration directory
-- UNIX: Using default library directory
-- UNIX: Configuring uninstall target
-- UNIX: Created uninstall target
-- UNIX: Detected compiler: /usr/bin/gcc    
-- GCC: SFMT enabled, SSE2 flags forced
-- GCC: All warnings enabled
-- Found ACE library: /usr/local/lib/libACE.so
-- Found ACE headers: /usr/local/include
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97  (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:166 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:54 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Then I use "locate pthread.h". Here's a result:

```
/usr/include/mysql/my_pthread.h
/usr/include/pthread.h
/usr/local/include/ace/os_include/os_pthread.h
```

Comment: Did you try `cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr`?

Comment: I try this. However, the results did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found TrinityCore need SSE2 to run. However, Raspberry Pi used ARM and doesn't support it.

http://www.trinitycore.org/f/topic/1518-trouble-with-your-trinity-install-readme-1st-faqs/